# How to specify the axis when using the softmax activation in a Keras layer?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, activation-function

The Keras [docs](https://keras.io/activations/#softmax) for the softmax Activation states that I can specify which axis the activation is applied to. My model is supposed to output an *n* by *k* matrix *M* where *Mij* is the probability that the *i*th letter is symbol *j*.

```
n = 7 # number of symbols in the ouput string (fixed)
k = len("0123456789") # the number of possible symbols

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu', input_shape=((N,))))
...
model.add(layers.Dense(n * k, activation=None))
model.add(layers.Reshape((n, k)))

model.add(layers.Dense(output_dim=n, activation='softmax(x, axis=1)'))
```

The last line of code doesn't compile as I don't know how to correctly specify the axis (the axis for `k` in my case) for the softmax activation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use an actual function there, not a string.

Keras allows you to use a few strings for convenience.

The activation functions can be found in [keras.activations](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py), and they're listed in [the help file](https://keras.io/activations/).

```
from keras.activations import softmax

def softMaxAxis1(x):
    return softmax(x,axis=1)

..... 
......
model.add(layers.Dense(output_dim=n, activation=softMaxAxis1))
```

---

Or even a custom axis:

```
def softMaxAxis(axis):
    def soft(x):
        return softmax(x,axis=axis)
    return soft

...
model.add(layers.Dense(output_dim=n, activation=softMaxAxis(1)))
```

Comment: I got an error "softmax() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis' " after I did this.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe you need a newer keras/tensorflow version...You could also combine `Permute` layers to move the desired axis to the end, use a `softmax` and another `Permute` to restore the old positions.

Comment: Or you can get `softmax` directly from the `backend` instead of `activations`.